# React Native Maps: Markers image doesn't show using Custom Marker in react-native-maps

Tags: android, google-maps, react-native, react-native-maps

I'm using `react-native-maps` but I faced a problem that after a lot of googling without answer makes me ask it here.
I'm trying to use Custom Marker for the marker in the map  as the following picture

[image]

- as I searched I found out that needed to use Custom Marker to accomplish the maker's design,  then I created a Custom Marker component

  ```
  import React, { Component } from "react";
  import { View } from "react-native";
  import {
  Text,
  Left,
  Right,
  Thumbnail,
  } from "native-base";
  const defaultEmployeeLogo = require("../../../assets/defualtEmployee.png");
  class CustomMarker extends Component {
  render() {
      return (
      <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', width: 140, height: 60, 
        borderRadius: 70, backgroundColor: 'orange' }}>
          <Left>
              <Thumbnail source={defaultEmployeeLogo} />
          </Left>
          <Right>
              <Text style={{
                  color: '#fef',
                  fontSize: 13,
                  paddingBottom: 2,
                  fontFamily: 'Roboto',
                  alignItems: 'center',
                  paddingRight: 10
              }}>Mohammad</Text>
          </Right></View >);
     }
  }
  export default CustomMarker;
  ```

when I use CustomMarker.js class solely it works fine and it shows the image but when I use it as the marker custom view it doesn't show the image

[image]

I don't know why it can't render the image with Custom Marker in android.
and here is my code where I'm using map, markers and custom marker class

```
return (
  <View style={styles.map_container}>
    <MapView
      style={styles.map}
      customMapStyle={customrMapStyle}
      region={{
        latitude: this.state.region.latitude,
        longitude: this.state.region.longitude,
        latitudeDelta: 0.4,
        longitudeDelta: 0.41,
      }} >
      {
        coordinationData.map(function (marker, i) {

          let lat = marker.latLang.latitude;
          let lang = marker.latLang.longitude;
           <MapView.Marker
            key={i}
            coordinate={
              {
                latitude: lat,
                longitude: lang,
                latitudeDelta: 0.4,
                longitudeDelta: 0.41
              }
            }
            title={marker.title}
            description={marker.description}

          >
            <CustomMarker />
          </MapView.Marker>
        })}
    </MapView>
  </View>
```

any kind of help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `SVG` for this https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-svg

```
<Marker
    coordinate={{
        longitude: lang,
        latitude: lat,
    }}
>
    <View style={{
        flexDirection: 'row', width: 100, height: 30,
        backgroundColor: 'orange'
    }}>
        <Svg
            width={40} height={30}>
            <Image
                href={url}
                width={40}
                height={30}
            />
        </Svg>
        <View
            style={{
                flexDirection: 'column'

            }}
        >
            <Text
                style={{
                    marginLeft: 2,
                    fontSize: 9,
                    color: '#ffffff',
                    fontWeight: 'bold',
                    textDecorationLine: 'underline'
                }}
            >{marker.title}</Text>
            <Text
                style={{
                    marginLeft: 2,
                    fontSize: 9,
                    color: '#ffffff',
                    fontWeight: 'bold',
                    textDecorationLine: 'underline'
                }}
            >{marker.description}</Text>
        </View>
    </View>
</Marker>
```

Answer (score 5):

My problem was solved right now.

I hope your problem will be solved.

#### This is my clean code:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {ImageBackground, Text} from 'react-native';
import {Marker} from 'react-native-maps';

export default class CustomMarker extends Component {
    state = {
        initialRender: true
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <Marker
              //...
            >
                <ImageBackground
                    source={require('../assets/cluster3_mobile.png')}>

                    // *** These lines are very important ***
                    onLoad={() => this.forceUpdate()}
                    onLayout={() => this.setState({initialRender: false})}
                    key={`${this.state.initialRender}`}
                    >
                    

                    // **** This line is very very important ****
                    <Text style={{width: 0, height: 0}}>{Math.random()}</Text>

                </ImageBackground>
            </Marker>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you must add style to ImageBackgrund , at least running in android shows this error. @Mahdi Bashirpour

Comment: Instead of using `native-base`, test this straightforward my code. Maybe it's a problem. Or else test the component code somewhere other than the map to see if it works there @Abdu4

Comment: If the whole thing works out of a map , then it is likely that the map with Component `native-base` is problematic @Abdu4

Comment: sorry this is not the issue, I think the problem is Android .@Mahdi Bashirpour

Comment: So use exactly my codes.
And rest assured that it will be true because I've tried it @Abdu4

Comment: Have u tried your codes on Android Phone? @Mahdi Bashirpour

Comment: and it worked? if yes would u share screenshot in order to show my employer  @Mahdi Bashirpour

Answer (score 3):

as of Oct 2019, the image can be displayed in the marker as along as the tracksViewChanges is set to true. I use FastImage but the general idea is to set tracksViewChanges to true and then to false as soon as the image is loaded so that there won't be any performance issue.

```
export const UserMapPin = props => {
  const [trackView, setTrackView] = useState(true);

  function changeTrackView() {
    setTrackView(false);
  }

  return (
    <Marker
      tracksViewChanges={trackView}
      coordinate={props.coordinates}>
      <View style={styles.imageIconContainer}>
          <FastImage
            onLoadEnd={changeTrackView}
            style={styles.someImageStyle}
            source={{
              uri: props.imageURI,
            }}
            resizeMode={FastImage.resizeMode.cover}
          />
      </View>
    </Marker>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem.

When you first load an application, the image does not show, but for later loading, this problem is resolved and show image.

Just enough after the image is loaded call `this.forceUpdate()`

```
const defaultEmployeeLogo = require("../../../assets/defualtEmployee.png");

<Image source={defaultEmployeeLogo} onLoad={() => this.forceUpdate()}>
    <Text style={{width:0, height:0}}>{Math.random()}</Text>
</Image>
```

You can track this:

https://github.com/react-community/react-native-maps/issues/924

Comment: I'm loading the image neither from web server nor AsynStoage, it's just in my local project.@Mahdi Bashirpour

Comment: No. You do not get an image from the web.
Your image is local. const defaultEmployeeLogo = require("../../../assets/defualtEmployee.png");

Comment: It does not matter at all.
Please try this `this.forceUpdate()` when loaded image or screen

Comment: beside that if I use image as a tag inside Marker it works properly,but I need to use it in my Custom View for marker since  I need to use text with a custom view a long side with iamge.

Comment: This worked for me  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51915353/react-native-maps-markers-image-doesnt-show-using-custom-marker-in-react-nativ/51916780#51916780 @abdu4

Comment: hmm, so why it doesn't work for me? which platform u are running the APP android or iOS? @Mahdi Bashirpour

Comment: running on android platform  @Abdu4

Answer (score 2):

@Mahdi Bashirpour solution works for me. just upgrading above answer.

Other Images stop working if we import 'Image' from 'react-native-svg'

My solution is below.

```
import {Image} from 'react-native';   // for other images in our render method.
import { Image as Imagesvg } from 'react-native-svg';

<Marker
   coordinate={marker.latlng}
   title={marker.title}
 >

<View style={{ height: 90, width: 90, backgroundColor: 'orange' }}>
      <Svg width={90} height={90}}>
        <Imagesvg href={marker_g} width={90} height={90} />  // Local Images
       <Imagesvg href={{uri:url}} width={90} height={90} />   //Server images
    </Svg>
</View>
</Marker>
```

Use 'Imagesvg' for marker image.
It's working for me on android 7 and 8.  React native version '0.55.3'

Answer (score 1):

This is another example

```
class PinMarker extends Component {
  state = {
    initialRender: true
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <MapView.Marker coordinate={coordinate}>
        <Image
          source={...}
          onLayout={() => this.setState({ initialRender: false })}
          key={`${this.state.initialRender}`}
        />
      </MapView.Marker>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: really appreciate your responses, but again the same result, the map loads but the image is not shown.

Comment: any other idea? @Mahdi Bashirpour

Comment: Because I myself had the same problem, I'm working on it right now.
I have come up with good results @abdu4

Answer (score 1):

I Had same problem , [from github post](https://github.com/react-community/react-native-maps/issues/924#issuecomment-416187595)

using below(MapView , Image) pattern first load problem will still occour

```
<MapView.Marker>
    <Image source={img_marker} />
</MapView.Marker>
```

so adopted below solution : trick is to save current selected marker id in redux

```
class Map extends React.Component {
render() {
    let {region, markers , markerClick} = this.props;
    const normalMarkerImage = require('../../images/normal_marker.png');
    const selectedMarkerImage = require('../../images/selected_marker.png');
    return !isObjectEmpty(region) && !isObjectEmpty(markers) ? (
        <MapView
            style={styles.map}
            showsUserLocation={true}
            followUserLocation={true}
            zoomEnabled={true}
            region={region}
            paddingAdjustmentBehavior={'automatic'}
            showsIndoors={true}
            showsIndoorLevelPicker={false}
            showsTraffic={false}
            toolbarEnabled={false}
            loadingEnabled={true}
            showsMyLocationButton={true}>
            {markers && markers.length > 0
                ? markers.map((marker, i) => (
                        <MapView.Marker
                            coordinate={{
                                longitude: marker.loc.coordinates[0],
                                latitude: marker.loc.coordinates[1],
                            }}
                            key={`marker-${i}`}
                            style={{height: 20, width: 20}}
                            onPress={e => markerClick(e, marker)}
                            image={
                                this.props.selectedMarker === marker._id
                                    ? selectedMarkerImage
                                    : normalMarkerImage
                            }
                        />
                  ))
                : null}
        </MapView>
    ) : null;
  }
}
```

**component Function**

```
markerClick = async (event, data) => {
    this.props.dispatch(
        setMarkerIconInRedux(this.state.popover.currentData._id)
    );
};
```

**Action**

```js
export const setMarkerIconInRedux = where => {
    return {
        type: 'SET_MARKER_ICON',
        _id: where,
    };
};
```

**Redux**

```js
export const currentSelectedMarker = (state = {selectedMarker: ''}, action) => 
{
    if (action.type === 'SET_MARKER_ICON') {
        return {selectedMarker: action._id};
    } else if (action.type === 'REMOVE_MARKER_ICON') {
        return {selectedMarker: ''};
    } else {
        return state;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved this issue by replacing 16-bit gamma integer Image with 8-bit gamma integer Image. It can be done in Gimp, once exporting Image select 8bpc RGBA.

Comment: can u please add an example as well?

Comment: It is not about coding, it is about replacing Image. Your Image should be in 8-bit gamma integer format.

Answer (score 0):

For my case the problem was only with remote Images so I solve it by a hack.

I just put one version of Image with zero width inside Text Component and one version out side Text Component. and suddenly everything's solved.

```
    <Image
     source={{ uri: "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/04/23/22/00/tree-736885__340.jpg" }}
     style={styles.companyLogoMarker}
     resizeMode="cover"
     />
     <Text style={styles.markerText}>
        {names?.[0]?.value}
       <Image
           source={{ uri: "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/04/23/22/00/tree-736885__340.jpg" }}
           style={{width: 0, height: 0}}
           resizeMode="cover"
        />
     </Text>
```

as of writing this Answer this is a bug in `[react native maps][1]` and not solved since 2017

Answer (score 0):

Add your custom marker component inside `<View>`
e.g. `<View>  your marker custom view  </View>`. Maybe it will resolve your issue.